# Plot two 3D graphics from own models in one plot in R

Tags: r, plot, graphics, 3d

I have a model like this

```
lmer(response ~ poly(pred1, 2) * poly(pred2, 2) * grouping_variable ...)
```

Since my grouping variable has two levels I would like to plot two 3D Graphics in one plot like this:
[image]

this is done with `scatter3d` from the `car` package. Unfortunately there is no option to plot an own model. There are some options to chose (linear, quadratic,...) but I would like to plot my model.

I was able to plot my own model with `scatter3D` from the `plot3D` package, but I could not find an option to plot both levels of the grouping variable.

Do you have an idea, how I could achieve this?

Here are some example data (I am not good in simulating data, but I think it should work):

```
library(car)
library(dplyr)
X <- seq(76, 135) + rnorm(sd = 2, n = 60) 
Y <- seq(65, 365, length.out = 60) + rnorm(sd = 4, n = 60)
Test.grid <-  expand.grid(X = X, Y = Y)
Test.grid$A <- 1
Test.grid$Z <- 2*X + 0.5*Y 
df1 <- sample_n(Test.grid, 60)
df2 <- df1 %>% mutate(A = 2, Y = Y + 50)
Test <- rbind(df1, df2)
X <- Test$X
Y <- Test$Y
Z <- Test$Z
scatter3d(x=X, y=Y, z=Z, groups = as.factor(Test$A), grid = FALSE, fit = "linear",  surface.col = c("red", "black"))
```

Comment: Would this be helpful? `plot3D::scatter3D(x=X, y=Y, z=Z, colvar = Test$A)`. `colvar` can define the color of each group.

Comment: Thanks xiliam. I can colour the dots in 2 colour groups with that, but I would like to plot the 2 models. So my goal are two coloured areas in one plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All commands from the `plot3D` package include a command `add = T`. With that it is very easy to plot the second surface, by just adding `add = T` to the second plot command.